# Can we fetch visualisation URL with Tableau REST API?

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau. We have a use-case and we considered Tableau to accomplish that. We are working on a search platform. As part of it, based on user search, we want to help the user with some analytics along with actual answer. So, our requirement is,

1. User asks a question
2. We get the information for that question
3. We created a hyper file using the information and published to tableau server
4. Now we want to create a visualisation out of published hyper file using Rest API and get the URL for the visualisation
5. Use Tableau Javascript API to show the visualisation for the user.

We are stuck at 4th point. As per Tableau documentation I could not find anything related. Is there a way to do this in Tableau. Can someone suggest if Tableau is an option for us?

Comment: Can you use the workbooks content_url attribute to get through step 4? https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#workbooks

You should already know the server name, and project folder so the last piece is the name of workbook in the URL if i understand correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to create a visualization with the Rest API or just get a URL? It seems like you haven't created a viz based on `4.` The API will allow you to publish a created viz then you can find the url for it, but the API will not allow you to create a viz using a published hyper file. You can connect to a hyper file using webedit directly in your browser and create a viz though.